# How to save draft of a long form in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher

I have a long form with over 80 input fields. After submission, it works fine and saves data in a neo4j database. I need to have 'Save Draft' function in case the users want to fill the form later. How can I implement it ?

Edit:

I am trying to save the form data (including empty input fields) into the neo4j database.

I have an array and the form in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mydata: {
                data1: {},
                data2: {},
            }
        };
        this.saveAsDraft = this.saveAsDraft.bind(this);
        <form>
            <MyInput 
                title="Name" 
                inputs={[{title: "name", inputType: "text" }]} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="freeText"
            />
            <MyInput 
                title="Email" 
                inputs={[{title: "email", inputType: "text" }]} 
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                type="freeText"
            />
        </form>
}
```

And I used following method to handle the form submission:

```
async saveAsDraft(){
    const name = this.state.mydata['data1']['name'];
    const email = this.state.mydata['data1']['email'];

    const neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')

    const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'pass'))
    const session = driver.session({database: 'neo4j'})
    const txc = session.beginTransaction()
    try {
       const result = await txc.run(
                'CREATE (:Person { name: $name, email: $email })',
                {
                    name: name, 
                    email: email                    
                }
              )
  await txc.commit()
        console.log('commited')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error) 
        await txc.rollback()
        console.log('rolled back') 
    } finally {
        await session.close()
    }
}
```

It works when the input fields are filled. But it shows following error when input fields are empty:

```
Neo4jError: Expected parameter(s): name, email
```

how can i handle the empty input fields here ? I want to execute the cypher queries and create nodes and relations with empty input values.
I also need to extract the data later to populate them to the form when the user wants to continue editing the form later.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's required to access the form answers from different devices or browsers, then you'll have to store the data into database.

If it's enough, that the users can access the saved form data only on same browser, you can use local storage to achieve that. Some state management libraries like redux and mobxstate tree offer persist feature, so you can persist the whole state of your app in the local storage with minor config.

Comment: users should be able to fill the form later, it could be after days or weeks later. and those drafts will be displayed in the profile page.

Comment: can you provide any example ?

Comment: Filling all my input fields is required for submitting form data. How to deal with required fields while saving the data as draft ?

Comment: the question is updated